# How to Extract YYYYMMDD from my database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have read most of the links on stack overflow on how to fix this but i still want some clarity, am using C# to select a timestamp (12/19/2014 2:34:09.808151 PM +03:00), i want to select the date only in this format YYYYMMDD (20141214). This is what i have:

```
string datepaid = "";
```

Then i perform the query

```
String SQL = String.Format("SELECT TRANSACTION_CASH_ID,SOURCE_MSISDN,AMOUNT,REFERENCE_ID, CREATED_TIMESTAMP, STATUS_DESCRIPTION,CASH_INFORMATION,(SELECT FIRST_NAME|| ' ' ||SECOND_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME FROM TAX_ACCOUNT_DATA WHERE AUTHORIZED_MOBILE_NUMBER = SOURCE_MSISDN) AS TAX_PAYER_NAME FROM TRANSACTION_CASH WHERE DEST_MSISDN = '12345678923'");
```

Then i assign it do a datatable

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    datepaid = row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"].ToString();
}
```

Then log the value.

My question is how will i get the date in `YYYYMMDD`, assign it to the string `datepaid` then use it in my Data table C#

Comment: Your day part is `19`. Where is this `14` comes from? You have `12/19/2014 2:34:09.808151 PM +03:00` as a string in your database? Can `timestamp` type hold this value? I don't think so. Even `datetime` type can't hold it.

Comment: Thats a mistake, it should  be 19

Comment: Never, I repeat *NEVER*, use `String.Format` to put parameters into an SQL query. Use parameterized queries instead. And no, there's no excuse at all for doing it with `String.Format`.

Comment: Actually, there are no parameters involved at all here, so the String.Format call isn't needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, if you scroll to the right, you'll see a where clause. I just presume that it doesn't make sense to have a fixed `DEST_MSISDN` in the code. Without doubt, the code as is doesn't make sense, as the parameter is left out. The fact that the `String.Format` is there, however, shows me that in the actual code, some parameter is inserted using `String.Format`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I did scroll, 3 times, to make sure that there was no parameter indeed

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You misunderstand what I'm trying to say :-) Right now there's no parameter, you're right. But I can see a fixed text in the `WHERE` clause. I can also see a `String.Format`. Both tells me that in his real code, there actually **is** a parameter that's put into the query text using `String.Format` and that he only simplified his code - maybe for testing, maybe for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates do not have formats. The date part of a DateTime value is returned by the [Date property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) just as the time part is returned by the [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Don't try to convert the date to a string, it's a sure way to get into conversion and internationalization errors, wastes memory, is more complex etc.

In general you should never work with strings when there is a concrete type like `date` or `numeric` available as this exposes you to conversion and internationalization problems that can never be fully addressed.

You can read the date from the `CREATED_TIMESTAMP` columns like this:

```
DateTime datepaid = (row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"] as DateTime).Date;
```

To retrieve only the date parts from datetime values in Oracle or MySQL, cast them to the `DATE` type. This type doesn't have a time portions  eg:

```
SELECT CAST(CREATED_TIMESTAMP AS Date) as CREATED_DATE, ...
```

This is mapped to DateTime on the C# side.

In all cases, you should convert the date to string *only* for display purposes, never for calculations, comparisons or passing back to the database. It's far too easy mix up formats and end up either with exceptions or worse, bad data. Imagine for example storing the value '10/1/2014' in a database - in the UK, that has the Latin1 collation. You'd end up with Oct 1, not Jan 10.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to format the data when calling ToString.

You need access to the ToString overloads defined on DateTime, however, and there are numerous pitfalls here.

First, if you know or can ensure that there is never any NULL marks returned from your database, ie. the column type is `DateTime` and not `DateTime?`, you can do this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    datepaid = row.Field<DateTime>("CREATED_TIMESTAMP").ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

If it can be NULL:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    DateTime? value = row.Field<DateTime?>("CREATED_TIMESTAMP");
    datepaid = value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : null;
}
```

Comment: No reason to convert to strings, DateTime.Date returns the date portion

Comment: But it doesn't have a format per se. When he says format and shows the format I'm assuming strings.

Answer (score 1):

First always use Command Parameters this will prevent you from SQLInjection and in this case sql server can cache this query, which will lead to performance optimization !

```
 String sql = @"
SELECT 
   TRANSACTION_CASH_ID,
   SOURCE_MSISDN,AMOUNT,REFERENCE_ID, 
   CREATED_TIMESTAMP, STATUS_DESCRIPTION,CASH_INFORMATION,
  (SELECT FIRST_NAME|| ' ' ||SECOND_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME FROM TAX_ACCOUNT_DATA WHERE       AUTHORIZED_MOBILE_NUMBER = SOURCE_MSISDN) AS TAX_PAYER_NAME 

FROM 
   TRANSACTION_CASH

WHERE 
   DEST_MSISDN = @Destination";   


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(connectionString, sql);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@Destination, "12345678923");
```

Also never ever Write columns like this, it is unreadable. Also structure your query, if you have bug in the query it will be impossible to find with your current structure.

About your question: You NEVER should format your date in the `DataSet`, because same `DataSet` can be used in two places with 2 different formats. In this case you should use two loops for changing the format of the date. This is bad usability !

You should change the formatting in the place(Page, Control whatever) where you need it. For an example you should show it in some Label in the Page.

```
Label1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

In other page can be:

```
Label2.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"]).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

EDIT: If you are not sure that the row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"] is valid DateTime, you should use `DateTime.TryParse`.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is another thing that's risky. If the value isn't a Date, it will try to parse the text using the current locale's format (which for most of the world isn't mm/dd/yyyy). If it is, it's equivalent to a cast to DateTime

Comment: Dates do not have formats. Using a string field to store a date would be a serious problem in itself. A parameterized insert query with date parameters doesn't need converting to any format

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which RDBMS you're using but due to the use of || for concatenation I'm going to assume Oracle or MySQL.

If you don't need to use the date anywhere other than your data table you could change your query to return the data in the correct format using `TO_CHAR(created_timestamp,'YYYYMMDD') as created_timestamp`

Comment: Bot Oracle and MySQL have a `date` type. It's far better to cast to it than convert to/from strings

Answer (score 0):

aside from the comments around parameters in queries, to get MS SQL ( if that is what you are using ) to convert a datetime to YYYYMMDD you can use this statement :

```
SELECT replace(convert(varchar(10),SYSDATETIME(),112) ,'/','')
```

Comment: Casting to date is easier, safer and doesn't make any assumptions about the user's locale

Answer (score 0):

First extract a DateTime object form your row.
Then format the DateTime to a string

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   // prbably some error handling here
   DateTime dt = (DateTime)row["CREATED_TIMESTAMP"];
   datepaid = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

Comment: No need to play with strings, DateTime.Date returns the date part